# Understanding an assembly interval check

Tags: assembly, att

```
leal -0x61(%edx), %eax
cmpl $0x19, %eax
ja ...                  ;jump if edx is not between 0x61-0x7a
```

According to the description the above code snippet checks whether edx is between 0x61-0x7a. If not, the jump is taken.
As I understand `ja` checks the ZF and CF flags, anf jumps if they are zero.
The only thing I think I understand is that the second line, which calculates edx-0x7a. If edx < 0x7a, CF is set to 1, and jump is not taken.

1. How is checked that edx is greater than 0x61? Does not reset the second line the CF all the time?
2. Let's forget second line. If edx > 0x61 CF is zero therefore the jump will be taken. This is inconsistent with the description.

Comment: This is bit of a trick. The key thing to note is that your are effectively normalizing the bottom of the range end check to 0x00 by subtracting 0x61 from _EDX_. The key part here is that _JA_ is based on an **unsigned** comparison. So you compare with the top end of the normalized range with 0x19. If the **unsigned** comparison (unsigned is important) is above 0x19 than _EDX_ was originally outside 0x61 to 0x7a .

Comment: You may ask what happens if _EDX_ was originally below 0x61. The subtraction would make them negative, however an unsigned comparison treats them as very large integers with the most significant bit set. for instance if _EDX_ had 0x60 in it. 0x60-0x61=-1 . -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF . As an unsigned number that wraps around to the high end of the integer range.

Answer (score 2):

`ja` means jump if *above* (unsigned), rather than *greater* (signed).  Michael Petch already answered this in comments, but I'll approach it slightly differently in case that's useful.

In C, this is doing

```
if ( ((unsigned)edx - 0x61U) > 0x19 )
    goto ...;
```

Using an unsigned compare on signed values gives you `>= 0` for free, because negative signed values become large positive unsigned values, larger than the largest signed value (`INT_MAX`), so the compare will have the same result as for a signed value above your threshold.

Subtracting `0x61` (with `LEA`) shifts the range from `0x61-0x7a` to `0-0x19`, allowing a single unsigned compare to check both bounds.

---

**2.**: Note that the comment on the `ja` is talking about the range of `edx`, while the `cmp` is testing `eax` (after subtraction).